# How to read JSON/XML/YAML data into Sphinx RST file to programmatically generate a documentation page?

Tags: python, json, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

Lets say I have a JSON/YAML/XML etc of zoo animals and I want to make some documentation for all of the animals in the zoo. So I have a JSON like:

```json
{
  "zooName": "C town's Zoo",
  "animals": [
    "tiger": {
      "species":"some_species_name_here",
      "weight": 120
    },
    "bear":{
      "species":"some_other_species_name",
      "weight": 100
    }
  ]
}
```

In another SSG, I could do something like

```
 > Bring in a JSON file from /data/myfile.json

 > Access some index of that file like [animals][tiger], etc... 

> Show that data as a part of the HTML template that is made by, say, `tiger.rst`
```

How would I accomplish that in Sphinx? Let's say I have an `animals.rst` with a toc-tree for all my animals and then a file like this for each individual one.

```
Tiger
=======================================

Tiger info here.

Species: 
[[ Access my json here and show content from jsonfile[animals][tiger][species] ]]

Weight: 
[[ Access my json here and show content from jsonfile[animals][tiger][weight] ]]
```

Comment: Would [doctest](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/doctest.html) do what you want?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a [Sphinx extension](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/extdev/index.html#dev-extensions) (e.g. dhellmann's [datatemplates](https://github.com/sphinx-contrib/datatemplates))... but a crude `update.py` preprocessing script would probably do:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""To launch: ``$ python update.py > animals.rst``  """

import json

def headline(text, adorn='='):
    return text + '\n' + adorn*len(text)

def main():
    header = headline('Animals') + '\n\nAnimal info here.\n'
    footer = '\n.. End of document\n'
    mask = '* {name} -- {species}'

    with open('animals.json', 'r') as infile:
        data = json.load(infile)

    print(header)
    for beast in data['animals']:
        print(mask.format(**beast))
    print(footer)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

For any more advanced layout, upgrade from Python string `format` to [Jinja2](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/) templates.

`animals.json` is slightly different from your example:

```
{
  "zooName": "C town's Zoo",
  "animals": [
    {"name": "tiger", "species": "some_species_name_here",  "weight": 120},
    {"name": "bear",  "species": "some_other_species_name", "weight": 100}
  ]
}
```

finally, add a rule to the Sphinx [Makefile](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) that triggers the script if JSON content changed.